# Some devices don't work on 3.0 USB port?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

My laptop a HP DV6-1149wm has 2x 3.0 USB, and 2x 2.0 USB ports.

Some devices will work fine on both, like flash drives, but some other devices, like my iPod, and my Android phone will not work on my 3.0 ports.  They just don't show up at all, lsusb shows nothing, nor syslog.

Any idea why it is device-specific?  Or is there any way to force my 3.0 ports to act as 2.0 for the time being? I don't have any 3.0 devices.

Comment: Can you post the results of a -- lsusb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which version of Ubuntu you are using. USB 3.0 is problematic (buggy) in all versions prior to 12.04 in my personal experience.

Your best options may be to upgrade to 12.04 (or upgrade your kernel to at least 3.2).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was on 11.04 but just installed 12.04 earlier today.   Anyway, I no longer have my iPod touch. otherwise I'd test it on my usb 3.0 ports right now

Answer (score -3):

Also, your drivers could not be fully functioning yet. There is a reason you're not supposed to use USB3 for important installs yet.

Comment: Says who? AFAIK, USB3 is fully supported by Ubuntu, and any problems are considered bugs.